# v-dialog don't work with v-hover on Vuetify 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I have next problem: when I added v-hover on v-btn v-card inside v-dialog don't working

Look at the code

```js
<v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="500px">
  <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
    <v-hover v-slot:default="{ isHovering, props }">
      <v-btn :color="isHovering ? 'accent' : 'primary'" dark v-bind="props" v-on="on">New Item</v-btn>
    </v-hover>
  </template>
  <v-card>
    <v-card-title>
      <span class="text-h5">{{ formTitle }}</span>
    </v-card-title>
    <v-card-text>
      <v-container>
        <v-row>
          <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
            <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.name" label="Dessert name"></v-text-field>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
            <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.calories" label="Calories"></v-text-field>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
            <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.fat" label="Fat (g)"></v-text-field>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
            <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.carbs" label="Carbs (g)"></v-text-field>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
            <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.protein" label="Protein (g)"></v-text-field>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-card-text>
    <v-card-actions>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-btn color="blue-darken-1" variant="text" @click="close">Cancel</v-btn>
      <v-btn color="blue-darken-1" variant="text" @click="save">Save</v-btn>
    </v-card-actions>
  </v-card>
</v-dialog>
```

But if I deleting v-hover it is working fine

I tried change v-hover on v-tolltip like other advice, but it is not working. Also, I tried

Answer (score 1):

I found decision. This is correct code for dialog

```js
            <v-hover v-slot:default="{ isHovering, props }">
                <v-btn v-bind="props" :color="isHovering ? 'accent' : 'primary'" dark>Add new product
                    <v-dialog v-model="dialog" activator="parent" width="auto">
                        <v-card>
                            <v-card-title>
                                <span class="text-h5">{{ formTitle }}</span>
                            </v-card-title>

                            <v-card-text>
                                <v-container>
                                    <v-row>
                                        <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                                            <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.name" label="Dessert name"></v-text-field>
                                        </v-col>
                                        <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                                            <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.calories" label="Calories"></v-text-field>
                                        </v-col>
                                        <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                                            <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.fat" label="Fat (g)"></v-text-field>
                                        </v-col>
                                        <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                                            <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.carbs" label="Carbs (g)"></v-text-field>
                                        </v-col>
                                        <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                                            <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.protein" label="Protein (g)"></v-text-field>
                                        </v-col>
                                    </v-row>
                                </v-container>
                            </v-card-text>

                            <v-card-actions>
                                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                                <v-btn color="blue-darken-1" variant="text" @click="close">Cancel</v-btn>
                                <v-btn color="blue-darken-1" variant="text" @click="save">Save</v-btn>
                            </v-card-actions>
                        </v-card>
                    </v-dialog>
                </v-btn>
            </v-hover>
```